# Excluding certain conditioned variable in calculation using nested ifelse statement

Tags: c, formula

I have a formula, says :

```
v12=-(ln(v6)*v6+ln(v7)*v7+ln(v8)*v8+ln(v9)*v9).
```

I have 0 number in one or two variables in the calculation. Since `ln(0)` is undefined, the calculation was not performed. Is there any way to ignore  any variables that contain 0 in the calculation and proceed without it? I tried using na, but it failed.

Comment: There is no function in R called `ln` as far as I know. Use `log`.

Comment: Hi, actually I am not really too sure about the language. I am currently using French-made geostatistical software called Isatis. It could be c++. I am just guessing, sorry

Comment: Just got informed, the language is actually c. my bad :-(

Comment: Err, it's always good to know which language you're looking at :S

Comment: Natural log in C is also `log`.

Comment: You can use [log1p](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) in C too!

Answer (score 0):

Two choices (one is **in R language** which is what you originally asked for :S ):

1) What you literally asked for, **in R**, by using vectorization:

```
vec = c(v6,v7,v8,v9)
result = -sum(ifelse(vec!=0, vec*log(vec), 0))
```

2) log1p() is the safer and numerically more well-behaved alternative for small numbers:

```
v12 = -sum(lapply(c(v6,v7,v8,v9), function(x) { x*log1p(x) } ))
```

You can use [log1p](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) in C too!

Comment: Thanks smci. I cannot see c, lapply and function in the software library. Not sure it is going to work

Comment: can you please not to use abusive language! if you are not willing to answer simply do not post. I keep changing the programming language because I have no idea what language the software developer use. I am not doing this in purpose. What I found in the library is only ifelse function and some other basic mathematical function.

Comment: ^ It very clearly says it's R, darnit, not C! Like you asked for. Try not to dynamically change the language on us every few minutes... :-"

Comment: ^^ But don't you know the file extension they used? .r, .cpp, .cc or what? Any README? What language do they usually use? etc. Dump us an `ls -aR` on the source tree and maybe we can make an informed guess.